# setting a gloable variable in Node red

Tags: javascript, node-red

I'm trying to make a lock variable in node-red. for that I've  wrote the following function:

[image]

the function code is  :

```
global.set("lockvariable","0");
msg.payload = global.set("lockvariable")
if(global.get("lockvariable")=="0"){
    global.set("lockvariable","23")
}else {
    global.set("lockvariable","0")
}
return msg;
```

So my question is since this not working, how may I declar globale variable in Node red !

thanks in advance for any hint!

Answer (score 2):

You don't mention in what way this isn't working.

But by inspecting the code, you have a typo on the second line - you are doing:

```
msg.payload = global.set("lockvariable")
```

where you should be doing a `get`. By calling `set` with a single argument, you are setting the value to `undefined` which is equivalent to deleting it.